# Div doesn't update in asp.net SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm working with `SignalR` and I don't want to use `JavaScript` to connect to the hub.

This is the part of my codes:

**index.aspx:**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div>
                <div runat="server" id="DivMessage" style="width:100%; height: 250px;"></div>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TextBoxName"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonLogin" Text="LOGIN" OnClick="ButtonLogin_Click"/>
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="ButtonMessage" Text="SEND" OnClick="ButtonMessage_Click"/>
            </div>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**index.aspx.cs:**

```
namespace ASPNetSignalR
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static string uri = "http://localhost:4933";
        private static HubConnection connection;
        private static IHubProxy proxy;

        ...
     }

     protected void ButtonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        RunSignalRClient();
     }

     protected void ButtonMessage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
        SendMessage("Ehsan: Hello!");
     }

     public void RunSignalRClient()
     {
        connection = new HubConnection(uri);
        proxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("ASPNetSignalRHub");

        connection.Start().Wait();

        proxy.On<string>("SendMessage", SendMessage =>
        {
            DivMessage.InnerHtml += "<p>" + SendMessage + "</p>";
        });
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        proxy.Invoke<string>("SendMessage", new object[] { message });
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(ASPNetSignalR.Startup))]
namespace ASPNetSignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, everything works correctly and `DivMessage.InnerHtml += "<p>" + SendMessage + "</p>";` runs (like the following image), but nothing shows in the web page.

[image: ImageScreenShot]

Where I wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show us the configuration of SignalR and the implementation of the hub?

Comment: Not sure why the `UpdateMode="Conditional"`? Try removing or call `updatePanel.Update` after setting `DivMessage.InnerHtml` in `proxy.on` callback

Comment: @DDDSoft Sure. I update my question. Hub and configuration run and everything work correctly. but nothing shows in the webpage

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thanks for your comment. But it not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
$("#DivMessage").append(SendMessage);
```